# Is it possible to sync dates (meta data) from a document library to outlook

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, view, outlook

I've created view based on "review date" column in a document library.  This works perfect showing the file name on the correct date.  I now want to share this with users in their outlook as a calendar?  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What version of SharePoint?  Online, On-Prem: 2019, 2016, 2013, etc.

Comment: we're using sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, syncing custom column date from a document library to outlook is not available. Also sharing document library with users as a calendar in the outlook is not available.

As a workaround, after connecting to outlook, create a new column then filter the outlook based on the new column.

[image]

1.View settings -> Columns -> New column.

2.View settings -> Filter -> Advanced.